mySQL: Forming a Partial, Disjointed Hierarchy
I'm attempting to create a hierarchy within the database I'm working on. In my particular example I am tracking whether members of a league are a coach or a player. I understand the idea behind a hierarchy and how it works but have not had to program one yet (we began with drawing ERDs and no coding). Right now I'm unsure if I'm trying to overcomplicate the problem or am just not understanding how I need to convert what I have in my ERD to my code.
To provide further context, the customer specification reads as such:

A player plays in a single team in a given season. However, the player may change the teams from a season to the next. For a player we keep the name (we want to search based on the last name), the date of birth, the jersey number (which can change when the player changes the team or from a season to another) and the parent contact mobile phone.


A coach coaches one or more teams per seasons, but at most 3. A team is coached by a single coach. For a coach we keep the name (we search based on first and last name), the date of birth, the year starting coaching and an email.


For the new entities, as applicable, the first, last and middle name components are at most 17 characters long. Phones are stored in the format: (999) 999-9999. Emails are at most 22 characters long.
Organize the persons associated with the league in a hierarchy.

The portion of my ERD that deals with this question is this:

The code I currently have is this:
CREATE TABLE MEMBER_BK(
    ID_BK INT PRIMARY KEY,
    FIRST_NAME_BK VARCHAR(17) NOT NULL,
    MIDDLE_NAME_BK VARCHAR(17),
    LAST_NAME_BK VARCHAR(17) NOT NULL,
    POSITION_BK CHAR(1) NOT NULL, # <P, C>, P = Player, C = Coach
    CHECK(POSITION_BK = 'P' OR 'C')
    );

CREATE TABLE PLAYER_BK(
    MEMBER_ID_BK INT,
    MEMBER_POSITION_BK CHAR(1),
    JERSEY_NUMBER_BK INT NOT NULL,
    PHONE_BK CHAR(14) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(MEMBER_ID_BK, MEMBER_POSITION_BK),
    FOREIGN KEY(MEMBER_ID_BK) REFERENCES MEMBER_BK(ID_BK),
    #FOREIGN KEY(MEMBER_POSITION_BK) REFERENCES MEMBER_BK(POSITION_BK),
    CHECK(MEMBER_POSITION_BK = 'P')
    );

CREATE TABLE COACH_BK(
    MEMBER_ID_BK INT,
    MEMBER_POSITION_BK CHAR(1),
    START_YEAR_BK YEAR NOT NULL,
    EMAIL_BK VARCHAR(22) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(MEMBER_ID_BK, MEMBER_POSITION_BK),
    FOREIGN KEY(MEMBER_ID_BK) REFERENCES MEMBER_BK(ID_BK),
    #FOREIGN KEY(MEMBER_POSITION_BK) REFERENCES MEMBER_BK(POSITION_BK),
    CHECK(MEMBER_POSITION_BK = 'C')
    );

Currently when I have the FK of MEMBER_POSITION_BK not commented out, I receive an 1822 error code which leads me to lean towards me overcomplicating this problem. Removing the assignment of MEMBER_ID_BK as an FK runs without the error occurring. In my search of an answer, I did see that I might need to involve indexing, but that's not something I've run into yet.

I do not know the stucture of your club. But why have players a phone and coaches an email? For me this belongs to the members. Even the Jersey_number and Start_year could be in the members. So you add a Coach_Flag to the members and you have only one table.   ---  The Stucture of the ERD makes only sense when a member can be player and coach. evern then could you define a role like: Player, Choach, Both.

I do agree that theoretically a person could be both a player and a coach, however, the customer guidance didn't specify. I'll assume since the divisions are under-18 at the highest, that you wouldn't have a player that could be a coach. The customer guidance also specifies for players they only care about the jersey number and parent contact number and for coaches their start year and email. I was also trying to keep the scope of the question focused on the hierarchy, as that's the trouble I'm having.

I did not see any hierarchie at all

Perhaps I'm using the wrong terminology. I assumed the parent table MEMBER_BK and the child tables PLAYER_BK and COACH_BK presented a hierarchy? If I'm wrong, please clarify so I can update the question to better reflect what I've presented. To clarify, what I'm seeking to understand is whether having the PK ID_BK as a FK in PLAYER_BK and COACH_BK would suffice. It seems to me that I'd need both the ID_BK and POSITION_BK as FKs so that a given MEMBER_BK instance will be put in the correct child entity.

Why would you want to have MEMBER_POSITION_BK columns in the two child tables? That information is stored in the parent member table already that you can retrieve via a join.

So I would just place the PLAYER_ID_BK as the PK/FK in the child tables? That makes sense to me, since it would link the entity instances, but I'm not understanding how the input for POSITION_BK is used to direct it to the correct child table. I understand the idea behind it, IE If POSITION_BK = 'P' it's linked to an entry in the PLAYER_BK table, but what is making the connection that 'P' = PLAYER_BK?

@Starr11B the drawback of polymirphic relationships is that they work from child -> parent direction, but not parent -> child direction. You first need to establish if the type of the parent, then join on the child or you need to left join on both children and retrieve the columns you need based on the type.

@Shadow I think I'm understanding. So really, the only connection would be when a query is done joining the two tables. So would I represent that by simply dropping the MEMBER_POSITION_BK attribute from the child tables and leaving the MEMBER_ID as the PK and FK?

Yes, that's correct. When you ask the users to populate the form asking for a person's details, you will ask for the correct information based on the type and insert into the  right tables.

You can use a combined key with ID_BK  and POSITION_BK  and use thaT AS REFERENCE:
adding a unique Key on id_bk, would not allow a member to have C and P, but i think in real live, one member could have both positions.
CREATE TABLE MEMBER_BK(
    ID_BK INT ,
    FIRST_NAME_BK VARCHAR(17) NOT NULL,
    MIDDLE_NAME_BK VARCHAR(17),
    LAST_NAME_BK VARCHAR(17) NOT NULL,
    POSITION_BK CHAR(1) NOT NULL, # <P, C>, P = Player, C = Coach
    CHECK(POSITION_BK = 'P' OR 'C')
  ,UNIQUE (ID_BK)
,  PRIMARY KEY (ID_BK, POSITION_BK)
    );



CREATE TABLE PLAYER_BK(
    MEMBER_ID_BK INT,
    MEMBER_POSITION_BK CHAR(1),
    JERSEY_NUMBER_BK INT NOT NULL,
    PHONE_BK CHAR(14) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(MEMBER_ID_BK, MEMBER_POSITION_BK),
    FOREIGN KEY(MEMBER_ID_BK,MEMBER_POSITION_BK) REFERENCES MEMBER_BK(ID_BK,POSITION_BK ),
    CHECK(MEMBER_POSITION_BK = 'P')
    );



CREATE TABLE COACH_BK(
    MEMBER_ID_BK INT,
    MEMBER_POSITION_BK CHAR(1),
    START_YEAR_BK YEAR NOT NULL,
    EMAIL_BK VARCHAR(22) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(MEMBER_ID_BK, MEMBER_POSITION_BK),
     FOREIGN KEY(MEMBER_ID_BK,MEMBER_POSITION_BK) REFERENCES MEMBER_BK(ID_BK,POSITION_BK ),
    CHECK(MEMBER_POSITION_BK = 'C')
    );

fiddle

By having ID_BK as the PRIMARY KEY, doesn't that already set it as UNIQUE? I do see what you mean that by having ID_BK being unique would prevent an instance in MEMBER_BK from being both a player and a coach. The customer specification doesn't call for that and extrapolating from the players needing an adult contact number, I'd assume a player cannot be a coach.

No every id_bk could have c and p and would still be unique, so it is needed to be made unique as the primary does it
